# what can prevent setstate from working correctly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter in one of my project pages set state doesn't work at all no matter what I do I tried every almost everything every time doesn't work so what think can stop set state from working?
note: I am using  provider and shared preference

Comment: Share your source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState(){}` only works in `StatefulWidget` class, I think you are using `StatelessWidget`. If you want to use it change your class to `StatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

actually, nothing can stop it from working, and because you are new I am inviting you to accept that there is not something wrong with flutter but with your skill in flutter.
if you provide some code we might be able to help